# How do I build a list of lists

Tags: netlogo

So I want to build a list x that looks like this: `[[a1 b1][a2 b2][a3 b3]...]`. A and b are chosen with `one-of listA` and `one-of listB` respectively. I can't find how to build a list easily, I can't just add an item to an empty list?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the dictionary entry for [`lput`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/lput.html) for the general syntax for adding to a list, and potentially [the programming guide entry](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/2.0/docs/programming.html#lists) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908793/netlogo-adding-to-list-of-lists) for some more info. For this specific question, have a look at the example below:

```
to build-lists
  ca
  let a [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]
  let b [ "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" ]

  ; Unordered version:
  let ab []
  repeat length a [
    set ab lput ( list one-of a one-of b ) ab
  ]
  print "Randomly sampled list:"
  print ab

  ; Ordered version:
  set ab ( map [ [ i j ] -> list i j ] a b )
  print "Ordered list: "
  print ab  
  reset-ticks
end
```

Which gives an output something like:

```
Randomly sampled list:
[[2 a] [2 c] [1 d] [4 d] [1 e]]
Ordered list: 
[[1 a] [2 b] [3 c] [4 d] [5 e]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on Luke C's answer, using, respectively, [`n-values`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-values) and the [concise syntax for anonymous procedures](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#concise-syntax):

```
let a [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]
let b [ "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" ]

; Unordered version:
print n-values length a [ list one-of a one-of b ]

; Ordered version:
print (map list a b)
```